# Make a downloadable file available in an API that returns JSON

Tags: java, file, servlets, download

I am developing an API in Java. It is basically a java servlet that returns content in json (`application/json`). Using a Tomcat server. One of the field in the response is supposed to be a link to a downloadable .txt file.

I wonder what is the best way to deliver this file:

Generating this file on every request seems to me killer, even having some cron to clean directories with files

Any way to give a temporary link only while that request for a period without saving to the file system?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you writing anything to any file system in any situation? This case makes no sense to me.

Comment: You can serve a file out of memory or a database entry or an offsite objectstore, or ....  Ultimately, it is just coding.  However, that doesn't avoid the "how to clean up" problem that seems to be your "killer" concern.

Comment: Rephrasing the question to make it more clear ; removing unnecessary tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say writing to the file system would kill your application, then I deduce from that that your IO performance is too weak for that, right? I mean, if you even would not have the storage capacity for that, then your infrastructure is not suitable for your application at all. I can only see four other ways for solving that problem (but maybe there are more, my list is not exclusive):

1. Store the text file in a database. The database should also store timeout information. Good if there are more than 1 application servers and there is a load balancer in front of them (but all application servers share the same database).
2. Store the text file in RAM, maybe using a cache library which does the cleanup tasks automatically for you - but be aware that a cache library will usually not guarantee a minimum storage time for each file.
3. Do not store the text file at all, but create it just when it is requested (no idea if that is possible in your application).
4. Do not provide a link to the text file, but directly include its content in the json answer (of course it would then be escaped as a JSon String), which means your server can directly forget about it when the answer has been sent, but the client _must_ download it without checking if it needs the file or not.

Comment: I do not know if it will kill the application, I have to create a cronjob to clean the filesystem in x at x times. I am reviewing the best option. it did not seem like a good option. But to have a download link I have to make a servlet for us to download to its respective file. Right?

Comment: You will need to solve the tidy up problem *no matter where the file is kept*.  Right?  'Cos otherwise the place that the files are stored (file system, memory, database, wicker basket under the stairs, whatever) is going to fill up.  So if that is your "killer" problem, think again.

Comment: Yes in any case there must be a cleanup task. Maybe your code does not have to delete every file one by one explicitly, but at the end the machine will have to do the work, even if you are using a cache framework or some "delete from ... where ..." sql statement for cleanup. If your infrastructure has enough power for creating all these files and serving the json requests, it will also be able to do that cleanup work.

Comment: You should also take care of security aspects - make sure that you cannot just "guess" the file urls, for example if your file servlet just gets a numerical file ids.

Comment: @TobiasBarth I will opt for option 3. I did not realize the security problem that you get up, can you explain? I'll create a .jsp page, which will serve as the download link. which by parameter will receive an ID from which I will search.

Comment: The security problem I am thinking of is: Your first download url is like "domain.com/download.jsp?id=1". The next caller gets the download url "domain.com/download.jsp?id=2", the caller after that gets "domain.com/download.jsp?id=3". So, the first caller can guess the other two URLs. I do not know if that would be OK for you or your customers. If the first URL would be like "domain.com/download.jsp?id=FAiwj389fJ32nf", and the next one "domain.com/download.jsp?id=l3F)k3mfsLKFMe3m,2" and so on, it would be harder for the first caller to guess the next URLs.